# Convert raw socket data into readable form

Tags: python, sockets

I am working on network analyzer. I have used code available form http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/.
The data section output of the program is as follows:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

M�Ak�0
      ���ZO�aQz��▒�&e��
                       �s�эU���V:����
                                     ����'qW�oձ.�U�UP7/�~
                                                         ��}�v��*n�<���J&��W/�%mb��$7��a���I�����G���D�RYO�&�Gx֗�uC▒~t�!B�7�.@ !�
��>�6��yԭ%��X9�7�i�i
 ��w���

`��
     O��?6�]��l���K��`

I need to convert this raw data into readable form and then analyze the data.I am using using python 2.7.

Comment: Looks like you are receiving some kind of Unicode text, and not really `iso-8859-1` as the header says.

Comment: Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 235
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Can any one help me to decode the packet?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `Content-Encoding` header, it says `gzip`. This means that the web-page is *compressed* using the gzip algorithm. As such it's binary data that you can't print out, you have to uncompress it first.

You can use the Python [`gzip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) module for that.

Comment: Yes I have uncompressed it using gzip Python module but the result after the uncompression and conversion is not working.